# Need to purge air from every radiatior?

Tags: heating, central-heating, radiator

I have a gas fired hot water central heating system. Water is circulated by two zone pumps at the furnace. There is an automatic fill valve.

I recently had work done on the heating system, and the water was drained from the system. We are now back online, and I have purged air from most of the radiators.

Several of the radiators are behind decorative screens that are built into the wall.  Do I need to bleed ***every*** radiator in the system to get it operating up to efficient standards? If I cannot get to a few, will they eventually purge themselves of air as the water is pumped through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Every bleeder.** Some may not even be on radiators (depends on system layout/design - bleeder elbows are common, but more on baseboard than radiator type systems.

If there is air trapped in a radiator, no water gets pumped through it. Circulator pumps are very limited devices. They don't do well at pushing air bubbles around the loop.